# TEST fine LIVE Form transaction error status Malformed 3045 currency field is missing

Tags: currency, opayo, malformed

I am integrating Sagepay form on a website. I have succssfully completed transactions in test mode but when I make it live I get the following error

Form transaction error status Malformed 3045 currency field is missing

Comment: So why does the code work fully in test

Comment: _“So why does the code work fully in test”_ – you’re seriously asking us _that_ about code we haven’t even seen yet …?

Comment: same problem with me...

Comment: I have facing the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940754/status-detail-3045-the-currency-field-is-missing

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not the Currency field, Sage Pay messages can be missleading at some points.

Please triple check that your encryption key is correct, I think you need a new one for LIVE mode, different than the one you use in TEST mode.

They throw that "currency" error because when the gateway tries to decrypt the message they cant and the first field that they look for is the Currency field.

Kind Regards,

Pablo

Comment: Thanks Pablo - I am using a different encryption key but do you know if they are site specific or anything like that. The only difference in the working file and the failing file is the connection to LIVE and the encryption key.

Comment: No, the encryption keys are not site specific, they are mode specific, one for LIVE, one for TEST

Comment: I have the same issue some can please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940754/status-detail-3045-the-currency-field-is-missing